# Print a new line in a table

Tags: javascript, html, newline

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Parse Prompt</title>
  <script language="JavaScript">
    var input = window.prompt("Enter a sentence");
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr Align='Center'>
      <th Width='100'>
        <H1>input</H1>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <script language="JavaScript">
      function parseStrings(input) {
        var parse = input.split(' ');
        for (let i = 0; i < parse.length; i++) {
          parse[i] = parse[i] + '<br />';
          return parse;
        }
        return input;
      }
      document.writeln("<tr Align='Center'><td>" + parseStrings(input) + "</td></tr>");
    </script>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

I am trying to parse the whitespace and print all elements in the array into an HTML table.

What I have done: I have created a function that would take in the `input` and try to split the white space and store that into an array. The way it's printing now is:

```
hello

,kedi,ekdier,
```

with each element after the first word getting a `,` and placed into the second line. That is my issue.

I have also tried without the function / array but it would do the following:

```
hello kedi ekdier
```

all in one line in the table.

Comment: You immediately `return parse` in the `for` loop. Why?

Comment: @Xufox thank you for formatting my script, and I return parse because I felt that it would help in the case of splitting, I may be wrong

Comment: If I don't return parse, I get everything in one line.

Comment: Just return `parse` outside of the loop and remove `return input;`.

Comment: @Xufox can you explain why that worked? Also, would I have to add a remove statement that removes the comma after every new line?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Xufox in the comments, the problem is that you're returning in two places:

1. Inside the `for` loop iterations (which is totally fine in normal programming, but you usually wrap it in a conditional)
2. After the `for` loop

Neither of these is wrong, but how you're doing it and what you're returning both are wrong. In this case, you want to **fully iterate**
over the entirety of your split input, and then instead of returning `input`, return the finalized array.

Furthermore, it looks like you're wanting to create a new table row for each "tokenized" item, rather than simply inserting a `</br>` newline.

I have created a JSFiddle for you here, that might help show what you need to do: https://jsfiddle.net/y3ezy0v6/

Edit: Without commas: https://jsfiddle.net/y3ezy0v6/2/

Comment: Question: why does your code print a , after every word? At the top left precisely.

Comment: You still need to `join` the array. The commas come from the stringification of the array, and since they’re outside any table cell, they end up outside the table.

Comment: You're right, @Xufox -- I didn't look at the top of the table. Thanks. It's fixed and updated